# Calling reset function with variables for multiple form is not working in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

This is reset function to reset form:

```
$scope.resetForm = function(formData,formName) {
                                      $scope.formData = {};
                                      $scope.formName.$setPristine();

                                }
```

I am calling this function on reset button for multiple forms. using this code:

```
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn btn-primary"
data-ng-click="resetForm(updateAddressData,updateAddressForm)">Reset</button>
```

Showing an error:

```
Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined
    at a.$$ChildScope.$$ChildScope.$scope.resetForm
```

Comment: You a passing `formData` and `formName` as arguments to your `$scope.resetForm` method, but then inside your method you are trying to access scope properties `$scope.formName` and `$scope.formName` (which is not correct). That is why your are getting the mentioned error.

Comment: How can I do it? because I have 5 forms and I want to make this code reusable. I want to pass form name and form data name as variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `function(formData,formName)` you are passing the formData and form, so you are passing the reference here.
And therefore  you do not have to use $scope, you can access them directly.

Use `formData = {}; formName.$setPristine();`

Comment: it is also not working.

formName.$setPristine is not a function
    at a.$$ChildScope.$$ChildScope.$scope.resetForm